# Is it possible to set partition accessibilityId for @iOSXCUITFindBy

Tags: ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have accessibility Id for element in ios Application, but part of this locator is variable. Is it possible somehow to set partition accessibility Id without variable part for @iOSXCUITFindBy

```
>  @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "You already have product *changeable part* in your list")
> public WebElement product
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course! just don't use *accessibility* to search, instead use *iOSNsPredicate* to match a regex like this:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "name MATCHES 'You already have product . in your list'")  
public WebElement product;
```

or

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "name BEGINSWITH 'You already'")   
public WebElement product;
```

Or as convenient for you.